# Convert last columns to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data look like the below

```
Rauf    11/12/2017   635  1240  1430  1630
Rauf    12/12/2017   630  1230  1430  1630
```

From Excel, I want to get the data as follows,

```
Rauf    11/12/2017  635
Rauf    11/12/2017  1240
Rauf    11/12/2017  1430
Rauf    11/12/2017  1630
Rauf    12/12/2017  630
Rauf    12/12/2017  1230
Rauf    12/12/2017  1430
Rauf    11/12/2017  1630
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. [What have you tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: check out the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal